# Loopback 4: How to edit metadata set by `@property` decorator on `Entity` props?

Tags: node.js, decorator, loopback

I use a third party Entity class with custom props. I extend it and need to add additional meta to already existing props defined inside the class I extend.

Here a code example. It doesn't work and is written only to explain better what I would like to accomplish:

```
export abstract class MyEntity extends ThirdPartyEntity {
  @property({
    // This is additional meta I want to add.
    myMetaProp: 'some value'
  })
  // This prop is already defined and decorated with `@property` in the `ThirdPartyEntity`.
  thirdPartyProp: string;
}
```

As mentioned above, this doesn't work. It produces this error - `@property cannot be applied more than once on`.
You can't add/remove or override alltogether the meta defined by the `@property` decorator.

I resolved to use this workaround `MyEntity.definition.properties.thirdPartyProp.myMetaProp = 'some value'`.

The question is: is there any better and declarative way of editing the props meta? I've tried with `MetadataInspector.defineMetadata` but accomplished nothing.